# Why did the MyPillow guy have a cameo in Unplanned?

Tags: unplanned

I saw the movie *Unplanned* and was kind of surprised to find that Mike Lindell, founder and TV spokesperson of My Pillow, had a cameo at the end of the film as a construction worker.

Why was this? Did he help financially back the film? Was he related to someone on the production team? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because he helped to finance the movie.

https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2019/jan/31/anti-abortion-movie-financed-by-my-pillow-guy-mike/

> It is a helpful victory at a critical time. An anti-abortion film partially financed by My Pillow founder Mike Lindell will be distributed nationwide in March.